# Angular Error : EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Users\Enoch\Workspaces\Angular IDE 2017 CI\myangular\dist'

Tags: angular, typescript

I reporting this, everything was working perfectly all of a sudden. I have this error when I run the ng serve or ng build.I am using Angular IDE

```
EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Users\Enoch\Workspaces\Angular IDE 2017 CI\myangular\dist'
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, lstat 'C:\Users\Enoch\Workspaces\Angular IDE 2017 CI\myangular\dist'
at Error (native)
at Object.fs.lstatSync (fs.js:994:11)
at Object.lstatSync (C:\Users\Enoch\Workspaces\Angular IDE 2017 CI\myangular\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:297:22)
at Object.rimrafSync (C:\Users\Enoch\Workspaces\Angular IDE 2017 CI\myangular\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\remove\rimraf.js:237:18)
at Class.run (C:\Users\Enoch\Workspaces\Angular IDE 2017 CI\myangular\node_modules@angular\cli\tasks\serve.js:31:16)
at check_port_1.checkPort.then.port (C:\Users\Enoch\Workspaces\Angular IDE 2017 CI\myangular\node_modules@angular\cli\commands\serve.js:110:26)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
```

Answer (score 0):

The file structure gets out of sync. If you're lucky you can end a process which will free it, otherwise restart you machine.